# Django. A good tutorial for Class Based Views

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

Is there any good tutorial for learn how to use Class Based Generics Views in Django?
I think that the documentation is not quite good and i'm a little bit lost when i try to do not usual things with the ListView, DetailView, CreateView, UpdateView and the other ones.
I've read the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/) , The [Django Book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/index.html) and a lot of google search.But i feel that i'm still not comfortable with my knowledges.
Thanks

Comment: Ok George, i thought that when there's no other good place to ask for, maybe stack overflow could be my solution. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, here are three excellent screencasts by [GoDjango](https://godjango.com):

[Part 1](https://godjango.com/15-class-based-views-part-1-templateview-and-redirectview/)

[Part 2](https://godjango.com/16-class-based-views-part-2-listview-and-formview/)

[Part 3](https://godjango.com/17-class-based-views-part-3-detailview-and-template_name-shortcut/)

Comment: wow, excelent material thanks Michael