# Django class based view with GET parameters

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-class-based-views

Using django rest framework I'm trying to create a view that allows to retrieve and update a single user but I don't understand how to do it. At the moment I don't care about permissions and authentication.

views.py

```
class UserDetailsView(RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    def get_object(self, user_id):
        user = get_user_model().objects.get(pk=user_id)
        return user
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    #rest of code
    url(r'^user/(?P<user_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.UserDetailsView.as_view(), name="profile"),
]
```

if I try to access localhost:8000/user/1 I get:

```
TypeError at /user/1/
get_object() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user_id'

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/user/1/
Django Version:     1.11.1
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    

get_object() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user_id'
```

I am missing something because with function based views everything works just fine. For example:

views.py

```
def game(request, id_game):
    # rest of code
```

urls.py

```
 url(r'^games/(?P<id_game>[0-9]+)/$', views.game, name="game"),
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, it's a kwarg not an arg. There's a difference. So you would need to do `user_id=None` in the `def get()` of your class based view. You can also access the kwargs by going `self.kwargs['user_id']`.

Secondly, since you're using the `RetrieveUpdateAPIView` you can just add the property for the URL PK Kwarg like this:

```
class UserDetailsView(RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'user_id'
```

And then you don't need to override the `get_object` method.
Some more info on the properties here: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#genericapiview

Note I'm linking to the GenericAPIView here because that's what `RetrieveUpdateAPIView` inherits from (or one of the classes).

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt answer. This solved my problem however I'm astonished by the lack of good documentation. I had already read that page and also django documentation page about class based views but non of them mentioned how to pass arguments to common http methods (GET and POST). It would be great if you could address me to a good detailed django guide

Comment: I just took a look at the first screencast in this post and, if that's your style, I recommend it. It looks pretty good https://stackoverflow.com/a/17414782/4832296

Answer (score 4):

You can access `user_id` as `kwargs` in `get_object`.

```
def get_object(self):
    user_id = self.kwargs['user_id']
    ...
```

Class based views offer far more flexibility and code reuse, but you do need to understand what each method means, and when it is called. Go through Django rest framework's documentation.

Answer (score 3):

You use custom kwarg `user_id` in your urlpatterns. You need to set `lookup_url_kwarg` inside View class.

Aditionally, to use full potential of generic views you should set the `queryset` field. If you do that, there is no need for overriding `get_object` method.

```
class UserDetailsView(RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    queryset = get_user_model().objects.all()
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'user_id'
    ...
```