# Form Validation using Django Templates

Tags: django, forms

I created a form inside my template, my problem is to get data without using forms module.

**(Update: I added my get `pk` from previous form and put it in my `pt` variable to insert in my table with `patient` field afterwards, the problem is it does not create new entry for my loop. I want to save tooth number and status)**

```
class DentalRecordCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'patient/dental_create.html'
    model = DentalRecord
    fields = '__all__'
    success_url = '/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        tooth = [18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 48, 47, 46, 45, 44, 43, 42, 41, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38]
        tooth.reverse()
        mytooth = {}
        pt = self.kwargs['pk']

       for t in tooth:
           mytooth["{0}".format(t)] = self.request.POST.getlist('tooth_' + str(t),False) # returns value each textbox from form tooth. Value for tooth status [decayed, etc.]
           mytooth2 = " ".join(mytooth[str(t)])
           form.instance.status = mytooth2
           form.instance.position = str(t)
           form.instance.patient = PatientInfo.objects.get(pk=pt)

    return super(DentalRecordCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Here is my model (Added)

```
class DentalRecord(models.Model):

    patient = models.ForeignKey(PatientInfo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    position = models.CharField('Teeth',max_length=200,  null=True, blank=True)  # 22, 31
    status = models.CharField('Status',max_length=200,  null=True, blank=True)  # decayed
    topArea = models.BooleanField('TopArea', default=False)  # boolean
    rightArea = models.BooleanField('RightArea', default=False)  # boolean
    bottomArea = models.BooleanField('BottomArea', default=False)  # boolean
    leftArea = models.BooleanField('LeftArea', default=False)  # boolean
    centerArea = models.BooleanField('CenterArea', default=False)  # boolean
```

My template.html (Added)

```
<form method='post' action="" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
               {% csrf_token %}
               <table  class="table table-responsive" id="dental-chart">

                  <tr>
                     {% with '48 47 46 45 44 43 42 41 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38' as list_lower %}
                     {% for y in list_lower.split %}
                     <td>
                        <svg width="50" height="50" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
                           width="10.8px" height="7.6px" viewBox="0 0 10.8 7.6" style="width:100%; enable-background:new 0 0 10.8 7.6;" xml:space="preserve">
                           <ellipse onClick="centerArea(this.id)" id="centerArea_{{ y }}"  name="centerArea_{{ y }}" class="ngipon" cx="5.4" cy="3.8" rx="2.7" ry="1.9"/>
                           <path onClick="leftArea(this.id)" id="leftArea_{{ y }}"  name="leftArea_{{ y }}" class="ngipon" d="M3.4,5.6C2.7,5.2,2.2,4.5,2.2,3.8c0-0.7,0.4-1.3,1-1.7L2,0.9C0.8,1.5,0,2.6,0,3.8
                              c0,1.3,0.9,2.4,2.2,3.1L3.4,5.6z"/>
                           <path onClick="topArea(this.id)" id="topArea_{{ y }}" name="topArea_{{ y }}" class="ngipon" d="M3.7,1.8c0.5-0.2,1.1-0.4,1.7-0.4C6,1.5,6.5,1.6,7,1.8l1.1-1.2C7.3,0.2,6.4,0,5.4,0
                              c-1.1,0-2.1,0.2-3,0.6L3.7,1.8z"/>
                           <path onClick="bottomArea(this.id)" id="bottomArea_{{ y }}" name="bottomArea_{{ y }}" class="ngipon" d="M7.1,5.8C6.6,6,6,6.2,5.4,6.2C4.8,6.2,4.3,6,3.8,5.8L2.6,7.1c0.8,0.3,1.7,0.5,2.7,0.5
                              c1.1,0,2.2-0.2,3-0.7L7.1,5.8z"/>
                           <path onClick="rightArea(this.id)" id="rightArea_{{ y }}" name="rightArea_{{ y }}" class="ngipon" d="M8.5,0.7L7.4,2c0.7,0.4,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.8c0,0.7-0.4,1.3-1,1.7l1.3,1.2C10,6,10.8,5,10.8,3.8
                              C10.8,2.5,9.9,1.4,8.5,0.7z"/>
                        </svg>
                     </td>
                     {% endfor %}
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     {% for y in list_lower.split %}
                     <td  class="col-sx-1"><input type="text" placeholder="{{ y }}" class="form-control" name="tooth_{{ y }}"></td>
                     {% endfor %}
                     {% endwith %}
                  </tr>
               </table>
               <div class="col-md-12">
                  <button id="dental" type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary pull-right btn-block">Submit</button>
               </div>
            </form>
```

**The error says that (Updated)**

```
'Could not send URL to django. Error 500. TypeError at /patient/dental/399 can only join an iterable'
```

I find the I find the class based views confusing, does anyone have a good tutorial on how to use it for CRUD operations?

Thanks

Comment: you have not declared any form_class in your view. thats the reason you are getting NoneType object for self.form_class, post your html and models  as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override `form_valid` method you will directly get form object. Move your logic from post method to form_valid. remove post method as you already mention success_url attribute. no need to redirect it explicitly

```
class DentalRecordCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'patient/dental_create.html'
    model = DentalRecord
    fields = '__all__'
    success_url = '/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        tooth = [18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 48, 47, 46, 45, 44, 43, 42, 41, 31, 32,
                     33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38]
        tooth.reverse()
        mytooth = {}

        for t in tooth:
           mytooth["{0}".format(t)] = request.POST.getlist('tooth_' + str(t), [])  
           # returns value each textbox from form tooth. Value for tooth status [decayed, etc.]
           mytooth2 = " ".join(mytooth[str(t)])
           form.instance.status = mytooth2
           form.instance.position = t

        return super(DentalRecordCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

ClassBased views [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17414622/django-a-good-tutorial-for-class-based-views)

Comment: is returned 'QueryDict' object is not callable, thank you for your response.

Comment: @CarlosAbiera, i have updated my answer, try this and let me know for any issue.

Comment: I followed your recommendations,  I forgot to include my foreign key field, please see my updated problem. Thank you for keeping in touch with my problem.

Comment: @CarlosAbiera did you moved your code to form_valid method? did your previous issue is fixed.

Comment: yes but still no good in saving data. base on my code above, its says 'can only join an iterable'.

Comment: post the ouput of `self.request.POST.getlist('tooth_' + str(t),False)`  line.

Comment: can you update the question with latest code, i can see there is still post method inside your class `DentalRecordCreateView `

Comment: `self.request.POST.getlist('tooth_' + str(t),False)` line gets the value of my `input type=text name="tooth_{{ y }}"` I updated my code and problem.

Comment: @CarlosFabiera replace `request.POST.getlist('tooth_' + str(t), False)` this line with `request.POST.getlist('tooth_' + str(t), [])` , as default value false is not iterable.

Comment: Strange! saving of data happened only in status field which is empty, and teeth field is fixated to 18. Foreign key assignment is good

Comment: print `request.POST` and add output to question, i guess you are getting data with different key name

Comment: I also tried `request.POST.getlist('tooth_%s' % t )` but no good.

Comment: A bit scary but this is how it looks. https://www.dropbox.com/s/okmnmtqwcbhbyx3/request.rtf?dl=0

Comment: there is issue in your loop, all values in tooth_? are empty inspite of tooth_22. but whats your loop is doing it updated the status value to blank.

Comment: you want to create multiple row for each tooth_?

Comment: Yes. its okay to leave it blank. Does it causes the error?

Comment: No currently there is only one row is created as the form instance is for one record

Comment: strangely when I tried to show the values using `me = str(t) + mytooth2
messages.success(self.request, me)  # display values` it went well.

Comment: is it working now? please upvote and accept my answer

Comment: Still no data being saved except for my teeth and patient fields