# Saving django form inside for loop

Tags: django, forms

This question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46617088/form-validation-using-django-templates/46617307?noredirect=1#comment80231011_46617307).

I'm planning to save values from my form fields. Below is my code for loop code:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
        tooth = [18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 48, 47, 46, 45, 44, 43, 42, 41, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38]
        tooth.reverse()
        mytooth = {}
        pt = self.kwargs['pk']

        for t in tooth:
            mytooth = self.request.POST.getlist('tooth_' + str(t), [])
            mytooth = " ".join(mytooth)
            form.instance.status = mytooth
            form.instance.position = t
            form.instance.patient = PatientInfo.objects.get(pk=pt)
        return super(DentalRecordCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

The problem is that I can see values using

```
show = str(t) + mytooth
messages.success(self.request, show)  # display values
```

but only the field `form.instance.patient` has value in my db. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the `form.save()` in your for-loop. That would at least explain why there is no data in your DB. 
It should look like:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
        tooth = [...]
        tooth.reverse()
        mytooth = {}
        pt = self.kwargs['pk']

        for t in tooth:
            mytooth = self.request.POST.getlist('tooth_' + str(t), [])
            mytooth = " ".join(mytooth)
            form.instance.status = me
            form.instance.position = t
            form.instance.patient = PatientInfo.objects.get(pk=pt)
            form.save()

        return super(DentalRecordCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: `could not send URL to django. Error:0` The only value I can see in my field is the foreign key and the repeated value `18` which is the first item in my list. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Could you please describe what you're intending to do with the form_valid function? I think I might have an idea how you could make it work.
I'm curious because your opening a dictionary and you start filling it without giving a key. A list is opened with `[ ... ]`.


   
`

Comment: Thank you for clarification. This post is in relation to my previous post, which some how solve the problem but gave birth to another one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46617088/form-validation-using-django-templates/46617307?noredirect=1#comment80231011_46617307

Comment: Then, the situation is a different one as the marked solution in your post is exactly what I was thinking about as the author fills the dict() correctly. How about using a HStoreField? According to the [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#hstorefield) it allows you to store a dict in the DB and you don't need to save your data in within the for-loop.

Comment: does it support db sqlite3?

Comment: No, it's specifically for PostgreSQL.

Comment: maybe `form.instance.save()` instead of `form.save()` could be a solution. Otherwise I have no clue, sorry.
 Is there any specific reason why you have chosen SQLite?